# Joomla ja mendozite template not leaving paypal button to working & proceed further for payment page but showing button as Buynow in my article?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

my joomla mendozite template not allowing this paypal button to work but if we post the button coding on any blogspot html editor or other normal html editors its working fine and allowing users to direct payment page in paypal. can any one help how to fix it?
my site link is as follows
http://seoquickheal.com/beta/index.php/seo-packages

my joomla mendozite template not allowing this paypal button to work but if we post the button coding on any blogspot html editor or other normal html editors its working fine and allowing users to direct payment page in paypal. can any one help how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is: We login to administrator panel, there we select

**global configuration** -> **text filters** -> and here: make no filters to all options or only to super user and administrator.

**global configuration** -> **site** -> here: Make default editor to None instead of TinyMCE